# new plot window plot every time I run my script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running a simple script in ipython, and no problem to get the plot and update the figure every time I run it

```
plt.clf()    
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.show()
```

However, if I try to plot multiple panels

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)
axs[0].plot(x,y,'bo')
axs[1].plot(x,z,'bo')
axs[2].plot(y,z,'bo')
plt.show()
```

a new window with the three panels is created every time I run my scrip (unless I exit and restart the ipython session). What shall I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`subplots` creates a new figure by default, but you can also specify which figure to plot into, if you do so then it will only open that one figure / window:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3, num=1) # force to plot into figure 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Since a new figure is created by subplots, also no reason to call plt.clf() then, right?

Comment: `plt.clf` will clear all existing figures. Only you know if that's what you want to do...